# Ошибка сегментирования

Tags: c

Не могу понять, почему падает.

```
struct Z {int x; int y;};

void calc(void) 
{
   // ...

   struct Z **z;
   struct Z z0 = {0, 0};

   *z = &z0;

   // ...
}
```

Вроде все ок?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ты пишешь по адресу, хранящемуся в z адрес указателя на z0. Так как z не инициализирована, он пишет в какую-то случайную область памяти

Comment: Точно!